# Way to fix some UI inconsistencies on Windows 10 being always blue

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors, desktop-customization

If you use WinPalleter to change most of windows UI colors (including classic colors tab), you can notice that most of them doesn't respect the color pallete, even if you fill all registries such as "Hilight/Highlight", "Accent colors" etc. Doesn't resolve all the issues.

Is there a way to fix any of these inconsistencies on color?

Inconsistencies on Desktop:
[image]

And on most of apps:
[image]

I know that StartAllBack exists, but it only works for Windows 11, and yea it pretty fix almost everything I wanted. But is not there another app tweak it?

Comment: The base Windows colors seem to me to be about as good as it gets.  3rd party apps seem to make things worse.

Comment: StartIsBack which is the Windows 10 version of StartAllBack exists and Start 11 which supports both Windows 10 and Windows 11 also exists.

Comment: @Ramhound yea, but StartIsBack++ doesn't show the option to colorize everything with accent color.